# Android the views are reset by orientation the screen

Tags: java, android

I've a LinearLayout with a default background and I change the background by click on a button. By orientation the screen the background is reset to default background.
I don't know why.

```
private Drawable backgroundImage;

public void InitializeUI() {
    parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_parent);
    if(backgroundImage != null) {
        parentLayout.setBackground(backgroundImage);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InitializeUI();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InitializeUI();
}
```

Changing the background with

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selectedBitmap);
this.backgroundImage = d;
parentLayout.setBackground(d);
```

Comment: You also may want to read what the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) have to say

Comment: I don't found a solution

Comment: I just gave you a link with 21 answers plus the documentation. If you don't have a solution from those then you need to explain how those aren't working for you.

Comment: The link are not the same problem. My problem is the background not a thread

Comment: Thanks the documentation has helped me

Comment: Yes, but it is for the same reason. You said you don't know why. Because the Activity is being recreated if you don't handle it. Read through those other answers, the links provided with them, and the docs. Then explain what you don't understand about it. You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onConfigurationChanged()` so it is as if you have just started the Activity